# How can I simplify the setting up of an array with a simple local method

Tags: c#

My code sets icon `svgs` like this:

```
Current.Resources["HomePageIcon5"] = (new[] {
      "resource://Japanese.Resources.5_Light.svg", 
      "resource://Japanese.Resources.5_Gray.svg", 
      "resource://Japanese.Resources.5_Dark.svg" })[thc];
```

It does the same for many more icons and the same string

```
"resource://Japanese.Resources."
```

Appears many times.

Is there a way I could create a local method that could do this for me? What I am looking for is something I could call like this:

```
Current.Resources["HomePageIcon5"] = X("5_Light","5_Gray","5_Dark");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like:

```
private static readonly _resourcesPath = "resource://Japanese.Resources.";

public void FillResource(string key, string value, int idx)
{
     var content = new[] 
     {
        _resourcesPath + value + "_Light.svg", 
        _resourcesPath + value + "_Gray.svg", 
        _resourcesPath + value + "_Dark.svg" 
     }
     Current.Resources[key] = content[idx];
}
```

and use it like:

```
FillResource("HomePageIcon5", "5", thc);
```

Comment: Did you mean  to have that return void ?

Comment: The middle one should be `"_Gray.svg"`.

Comment: it is yes to both

Answer (score 1):

The exact implementation for your request will be the following:

```
public string[] GetFormattedResources(params string[] strings)
{
    const string STRING_FORMAT = "resource://Japanese.Resources.{0}.svg";
    return strings.Select(str => string.Format(STRING_FORMAT, str)).ToArray();
}
```

This function uses the [params](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) keyword for grouping the strings and [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) functions to handle the collection easily. (For example: [Select](https://www.dotnetperls.com/select))

The call will be as follows:
`Current.Resources["HomePageIcon5"] = GetFormattedResources("5_Light","5_Gray","5_Dark");`